# Benefit of Single S#arp Arch assembly using ILMerge

Tags: performance, s#arp-architecture, ilmerge

Is there any performance issue/or any negative effect of having a single assembly referenced in many layers of on application as we are merging all S#arp Arch dlls into one now? What are the benefits except ease of deployment? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Kzu some time ago wrote his [experience](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2009/02/23/LeveragingILMergetosimplifydeploymentandyourusersexperience.aspx) with ILMerge and Moq.
From a performance point of view there is no issue, is only merging.

HTH

Comment: Robie - sorry for not chiming in earlier. The only benefit from the merge is the ease of deployment. As far as negative effects, I use this every day in production on a large system, no side effects have been noted.

Also - the assemblies have been merged since at least April or May.